# New connection every time I execute a query?

Tags: c++, mysql

I am using the MySQL C++ connector.

It shows how to make a simple connection like this:

```
sql::Driver* driver = get_driver_instance();
std::auto_ptr<sql::Connection> con(driver->connect(url, user, pass));
con->setSchema(database);
std::auto_ptr<sql::Statement> stmt(con->createStatement());
...
```

What I am wondering is. Should I do this every time I want to execute something? Should I make a new connection object, execute my query, do what I want with the results, then dispose of the connection and all and repeat when I need to execute something else? What should the scope of a connection object be?

It is for a game server, the server will do login, logout, sessions, record stats, chat logs, etc.

At any given time, the game server only needs 1 connection as it runs on a single thread.

Thanks

Comment: it depends - what type of application is it?

Comment: @DanielA.White It is for a game server, the server will do login, logout, sessions, record stats, chat logs, etc.

Comment: *cough* [Connection Pooling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) *cough* - code should usually use a locally-scoped/owned connection, but it is "relatively expensive" to establish a connection each time.

Comment: Is there an example out there of connection pooling with the c++ connector?

Comment: The game server only runs on a single thread btw...

Comment: Internets found me this: http://www.tidytutorials.com/2009/07/mysql-connector-c-database-pool.html YMMV.

Comment: (For a single-threaded application without re-entrant connections, a "singleton connection" might look more attractive - being effectively a crude CP with a single connection. I'm still in favor of an approach that requires "releasing", even implicitly, of the connection when the local use is finished.)

Comment: @user2864740 any examples of a singleton connection with c++ connector? Do I just create a connection object and never close it?

Comment: @Milo In the most basic sense - yes. Make sure to prevent cross-access transactions (i.e. commit/rollback all transactions in the applicable scope, else they can bite across an effectively shared connection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can get the driver instance and create only one connection when your application starts up,
and keep them in any variables(e.g., a singleton variable of your own style),
and use the connection variable whenever you execute queries.

- Caution: Be careful the DB connection not to be timed out.

Comment: How can I make it never timeout and autoreconnect?

Comment: @Milo: You need administrator privilege for your MySQL server, and you can set the default timeout values(maybe 28800 seconds) in the MySQL configuration file. Please search with the keyword 'mysql timeout' or something for more detailed information. (*)